# How to deal with promises in loop?

Tags: node.js, promise, sails.js, q, waterline

This is what I would like to do

```
var response = [];

Model.find().then(function(results){
   for(r in results){
      MyService.getAnotherModel(results[r]).then(function(magic){
          response.push(magic);
      });          
   }
});

//when finished
res.send(response, 200);
```

however it returns just [] because the async stuff is not ready yet. I am using sails.js that uses Q promise. Any ideas how to return a response when all async calls are finished?

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#query-methods (promise methods)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since waterline uses **Q**, you can use the `allSettled` method.
You can find [more details on **Q** documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination).

```
Model.find().then(function(results) {
  var promises = [];
  for (r in results){
    promises.push(MyService.getAnotherModel(results[r]));
  }

  // Wait until all promises resolve
  Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(result) {
    // Send the response
    res.send(result, 200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't do that, you have to wait for the asynchronous functions to complete.

You can either create something yourself, or use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) middleware, or use built in features, as noted in Florent's answer, but I'll add the other two here anyway :

```
var response = [];

Model.find().then(function(results){
   var length = Object.keys(results).length,
       i = 0;
   for(r in results){
      MyService.getAnotherModel(results[r]).then(function(magic){
          response.push(magic);
          i++;
          if (i == length) {
              // all done
              res.send(response, 200);
          }
      });     
   }
});
```

or with async

```
var response = [];

Model.find().then(function(results){
   var asyncs = [];
   for(r in results){
       asyncs.push(function(callback) {
           MyService.getAnotherModel(results[r]).then(function(magic){
               response.push(magic);
               callback();
           })
       });
   }
   async.series(asyncs, function(err) {
       if (!err) {
           res.send(response, 200);
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at jQuery deferred objects:
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Specifically, .when()
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Where a in a node.js context here.

Comment: Ah sry my bad.. took a quick look

Comment: That's what the "delete" link under the answer is for. :-)